# How to prevent the on ("click") event from activating when I'm doing drag?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map and in each path I have an `on("click")` event, this should be activated only when I click on a `path`, but it is activated at the end when the `drag` event ends. How can I make the click event activate, only when I click on a `path`?

this is my code:

```
      g.selectAll(".mpio")
        .data(topojson.feature(co, co.objects.mpios).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          return "mpio " + "_" + d.id + " " + d.properties.dpt
        })
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click",function(){
        alert("click")
        })
    })
```

this is my original code(problem original)

```
   g.selectAll('path')
    .data(features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .classed('map-layer', true)
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('colorOriginal', fillFn)
    .attr('departamento', function(d){
      return d.properties.NOMBRE_DPT;
    })
    .attr('idDepartamento', function(d){
      return d.properties.DPTO;
    })
    .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
    .style('fill', fillFn)
    /*.on('mouseover', mouseover)
    .on('mouseout', mouseout)*/
    .on('click', function(d){
      d3.select("#nombredepto").text(nameFn(d));
      d3.selectAll("path").style("stroke",function(){
        d3.select(this).transition().ease("linear").duration(500).style("fill",d3.select(this).attr("colorOriginal"))
      })
      d3.select(this).transition().ease("linear").duration(500).style("fill","#2e3c61");

      $scope.select_deptos={ "DPTO": d.properties.DPTO, "NOMBRE_DPT": d.properties.NOMBRE_DPT};
      $scope.sendFiltros.departamento=$scope.select_deptos.DPTO;
      $scope.aFiltros.departamento=[$scope.select_deptos];
      $scope.fn_mapa();

    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dkn5Lw97/

Answer (score 1):

From [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a84aeb78fea81e1ad806), you can add `if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;` into your click event to prevent it from happening when a zoom is happening.

```
.on("click",function(){
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
    alert("CLICKED!!")
  })
```

[Here is an implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/qm2q18kg/11/), from your fiddle.

Comment: thanks.. but It's strange, I know it works but in my real example nothing happens when I do drag or when I click ...

Comment: If you can post the code to where its not working that would be great. If we can't properly reproduce your problem, we can't properly answer your question.

Comment: I don't see any reason as to why this shouldn't work in the updated code.

Comment: I do not either ... I even erase everything and put alert ("clicked") but nothing works. always return true

Comment: try putting `if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return false;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168945/discussion-between-pmkro-and-yavg).

Answer (score 0):

check out [onmousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousedown) and [onmouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseup) to have a little more control.

A `click` is a full completion of both of these events (mouse down, then mouse up). I think you're looking for the mouse down even.

Comment: That's a comment but not an answer.